# How to both declare a Clojure function and immediately run from Java code using the clojure-utils?

Tags: java, clojure, clojure-java-interop

I want to declare a Clojure function and instantly evaluate it in the Java code using clojure-utils. How to do this?

The code I'm using is this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String s = "(defn fun[lst] (map #(/ % 2) lst))" +
               "(list* (#'clojure.core/fun '(1 2 3 4 5)))";
    System.out.println("Evaluating Clojure code: " + s);
    Object result = mikera.cljutils.Clojure.eval(s);
    System.out.println("=> " + result);
}
```

If I just use the following expression in the string variable `s`, it will work fine:

`(list* (map #(/ % 2) '(1 2 3 4 5)))`

And the Java Compiler will show:

`=> (1/2 1 3/2 2 5/2)`

But if I try to both declare my function and then try to call it from the code, like this:

```
String s = "(defn fun[lst] (map #(/ % 2) lst))" 
         + "(list* (fun '(1 2 3 4 5)))";
```

The Compiler will only show this:

```
Evaluating Clojure code:

(defn fun[lst] (map #(/ % 2) lst))(list* (#'clojure.core/fun '(1 2 3 4 5)))
=> #'clojure.core/fun
```

UPDATE:
I wrote this construction, it's awful, but it works:

```
String s = 
"(do 
    (defn main[lst]

      (defn fun[lst]
        (map #(/ % 2) lst))

      (list* (fun lst))) 

    (main '(1 2 3 4 5)))"
```

Result:
`=> (1/2 1 3/2 2 5/2)`

UPDATE 2 (Fixed):

```
(do 
    (defn fun[lst]
        (map #(/ % 2) lst))

    (list* (fun '(1 2 3 4 5))))
```

Comment: Yes, here you have one expression, so it works... You don't need the main. You will define the function every time you execute the main function...  :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a REPL, so it will only read one s-expression and evaluate it. You should eval every one.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    clojure("(defn fun[lst] (map #(/ % 2) lst))");
    clojure("(list* (#'clojure.core/fun '(1 2 3 4 5)))");
}

public static Object clojure(String s) {
    System.out.println("Evaluating Clojure code: " + s);
    Object result = mikera.cljutils.Clojure.eval(s);
    System.out.println("=> " + result);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I figured out that it is also possible to perform this as one expression. I updated my post to show how. Maybe this solution isn't quite good looking or elegant but, at least, it does what I wanted.

Comment: But what could be the best way to invoke Clojure code in Java? Can you show how to call some Clojure script from Java and is it possible to include a `.clj` script file inside a Java Project tree?

Comment: You can use load-string : http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/load-string

Answer (score 2):

You are just using a String evaluation. But it's more obvious to directly use interoperation with Clojure.

For example you could use load-string function :

```
IFn loadString = Clojure.var("clojure.core", "load-string");
Object result = loadString.invoke("(println \"Appel\")(your clojure code)");
```

On interoperability : http://clojure.github.io/clojure/javadoc/

Comment: I change it because it's outdated